# How to convert char[] to char?

Tags: c#, string

I am new to C#. I am trying to declare a `char` array that contains few string values. Trying to use the `ToCharArray()` method to copy the string to a char array it return character array of a string. However, I get the error saying it cannot implicitly convert `char[]` to `char`.

Here's the code I have written:

```cs
char[] country= new char[5];
country[1] = "japan".ToCharArray();
country[2] = "korea".ToCharArray();
```

It works when I write it like this:

```cs
char[] country= "japan".ToCharArray();
```

but I want to use it in an array so I can randomize and choose an element from any of 5 values assigned. I would really appreciate if anyone could help, thanks.

Comment: You need a string array `string[]` or two dimension char array `char[][]`

Comment: how _would_ you convert an array of chars into _one single character_? which one would you chose? this conversion does not _make any sense_.

Comment: In the last section you tell what you want to do with it. If that is what you actually want you don't need a char array for that. A simple array of strings would be sufficient. a string has an indexer you can retrieve single char from that you don't need a char array for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you try to have array of char arrays:

```cs
char[][] countries = new char[5][];
countries[1] = "japan".ToCharArray();
countries[2] = "korea".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Every element in the array is one character.
So country[0] is "j", country[1] is "a" and so on.

with

```
country[1] = "japan".ToCharArray();
```

you try to put an array into a char, and give you an error.
Perhaps you want a list of chars. So you can use an array of array or a list of country.
for the first country for example

```
List<string> country = new List<string>() {
    "japan",
    "korea"
};

var random = new Random();
var character = country[0][random.Next(0, country[0].Length)];
```